# How to make responsive hamburger menu with Bootstrap / React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

EDIT: I believe my issue is loading in the jquery and bootstrap JS scripts. How do I do this in React?

I have been trying to optimize my React website for mobile and have a Navbar that converts to a hamburger menu-style navbar when on mobile devices. So far, following the [Bootstrap Navbar Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler), I have been able to get my navbar to remove the items and show a hamburger icon when shrunk to a mobile size, but when I click the icon, nothing drops down.

Something to note: I pass the classes to my Navbar using props every time I load a page so that I can have various Navbar styles for different pages using one component. I will provide one such call in my About.js (page for my "About Me" page in my portfolio) that is the same as most others.

Navbar.JS

```
// navigation bar class
class NavBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav id={this.props.navId} className={this.props.class}>
                <li id={this.props.logoId} className={this.props.logoClass}><p>{this.props.logoText}</p></li>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"><i className="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul id="links" className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item active textlink"><Link className="nav-link" to="/home">Home</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item active textlink"><Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About Me</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item active textlink"><Link className="nav-link" to="/projects">Projects</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item active"><a className="nav-link" target="blank" href="https://github.com/QuintonPrice"><i className="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item active"><a className="nav-link" target="blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/quinton-price/"><i className="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav >
        );
    }
}

export default NavBar;
```

Example call of Navbar component in my About page (this is the same call that I use for all other pages but home page so far)

```
<Navbar navId="navb" logoId="logo" logoText="qprice" logoClass="mr-auto" class="navbar bg-white navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-fixed-top shadow ml-auto"/>
```

Navbar.css (NOTE: .navHome class is for the navbar displayed on home page, and .navb is for the navbar style I use on every other page):

```
/* nav bar */
nav {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* qprice logo */
#logo p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #52B788;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

/* nav bar home links */
#navHome a {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

#navHome a:hover, #navb a:hover {
    color: #52B788;
}

/* nav bar home list items */
#navHome li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .5rem;
}

/* nav links */ 
#navb a {
    color: #343a40;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

/* navigation list items */
#navb li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .5rem;
}

/* navbar link hover */
.textlink a:hover {
    color: #52B788;
}

.textlink a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #52B788;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out .05s;
  }

.textlink a:hover::before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

.fab {
    margin-right: .7rem;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

.fab:hover {
    color: #52B788;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: Your `<div className="collapse navbar-collapse">` is missing an `id="navbarTogglerDemo03"` to connect it to the navbar-toggler.

Comment: After adding the ID, I still run into the same issue

Comment: Good question.  That is weird.  My hamburger menu works here:  https://jsbin.com/mufahar/1/edit?html,output .  But while the hamburger nav still renders in my React app, when I click on the hamburger nothing happens:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kxakol?file=src/index.js .  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem yesterday.  I solved it by moving the script tags to the bottom of the html file before the closing body tag and rearranging the order so that the JQuery script runs first before the Bootstrap script.

Comment: I tried doing this, but unfortunately no cigar. Are you using the bootstrap-react program or just using bootstrap like normal?

Comment: I was not using it with react but I thought calling the scripts in the correct order might help.  Sorry it didn't work for you.  I can look into it further if you send me a link to the repo.

Comment: Here's a link to my repo: https://github.com/QuintonPrice/Portfolio